# Convert a json to a long data frame in R

Tags: r, json, list

I want to convert an json object to a data frame using R.

The data I am working with look like this:

```
{"A": [123, 234, 345]}
{"B": [1213, 132, 342, 1235]}
{"C": [132, 12]}
```

I want to convert this something like this:

```
| Name | Value |
| ---- | ----- |
| A    | 123   |
| A    | 234   |
| A    | 345   |
| B    | 1213  |
| B    | 132   |
| B    | 342   |
| B    | 1235  |
| C    | 132   |
| C    | 12    |
```

The dataset is quite large (more than 1M entries) so it would be great if the method is scalable.

Comment: How is that data stored? In a text file?

Comment: Yes, as a `.jsonl` file. I tried `read_lines` and `stream_in` to import the file.

Comment: does `stack(sapply(your_string, rjson::fromJSON, USE.NAMES = FALSE))` work?\

Comment: post the output of `dput(head(your_json_string))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string <- c("{\"A\": [123, 234, 345]}", "{\"B\": [1213, 132, 342, 1235]}",
            "{\"C\": [132, 12]}")

stack(sapply(string, rjson::fromJSON, USE.NAMES = FALSE))

  values ind
1    123   A
2    234   A
3    345   A
4   1213   B
5    132   B
6    342   B
7   1235   B
8    132   C
9     12   C
```

Comment: It just worked perfectly. Much appreciated!